# how to store newly created solidity contract address in another contract securely

Tags: contract-design

I am making an app where you can make battles with other people. I have created a `Battle` contract that is created for each new battle and I have created a `Battles` contract to keep track of all battle contract addresses and all player addresses.

Now what is the best way to create a new battle contract and then store that battle contract address and player address in the `Battles` contract?

I need to make sure that `Battles` contract which keeps track of all battles and players cannot be altered publicly.

What is the best way to do this?

Should the user create a `Battle` contract representing a new battle and from within the `constructor function` of that new contract, send a `transaction` to `Battle` contract to store the new battle contract address?

Or should the user make a transaction the the parent `Battles` contract and the parent `Battles` contract then makes a transaction to create a new battle? Could the parent `Battles` contract then receive the newly created contract address immediately for it to store?

Also does this make sense for a `contract design` to create a new contract for each individual battle and then have one parent contract store addresses for all the individual battle contracts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [smart contract variable storage](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28356/smart-contract-variable-storage)

Comment: @Зелёный I'm not asking how to store variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should learn to use [Solidity Libraries](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#libraries) so you don't have to create a new contract for each battle. Contract creation is expensive, where as libraries allow you to create the contract once but store the data it uses elsewhere. In this case the battle functionality would live in the `library` contract and the data for each battle would live in the battles contract.

If you don't use libraries, then as you suggested, the battles contract should create individual battle contracts. Executing `new Battle(constructor args)` within the battles contract will return the `address` of the new contract. See the doc on [creating contracts via new](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#creating-contracts-via-new). Note the doc shows casting of the contract directly to the contract type, although you can keep it as an address.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this is that all the ether that each player contributes for each battle will be stored in a single contract. Central Point of attack :/

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference if the contract is appropriately audited and secure. Ether available to individual players should still only be accessible to the users involved within their games. But you're right, it is a more centralised point of risk.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure it is any worse, because in the alternative, all the newly created contracts will be the same so any security vulnerabilities any individual one has they will all have.